# How do I make my np.split end in an equal division?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, split, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am rehearsing to improve my skills on developing a game, using a reinforcement learning tutorial, but then I run into trouble making the np.split performing correctly (i.e. not resulting in an equal division). The code below shows the reward definition session, while defining the parameters of the environment in another py file. The following line then causes the problem displayed in the traceback info part.

```
rewards_per_thousand_episodes = np.split(np.array(rewards_all_episodes), num_episodes/1000)
```

Tried to look for a solution to the issue, yet in vain. Any suggestions to a solution will be highly appreciated...;o)

Env definition:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import random
import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

env = gym.make("FrozenLake-v1")
env.reset()

# Construct Q-table, and initialize all the Q-values to zero for each state-action pair

action_space_size = env.action_space.n
state_space_size = env.observation_space.n

q_table = np.zeros((state_space_size, action_space_size))

print("\nq_table")
print(q_table)

# Initializing Q-Learning Parameters

num_episodes = 10000 # total number of episodes the agent is to play during training
max_steps_per_episode = 100 # maximum number of steps that agent is allowed to take within a single episode

learning_rate = 0.1
discount_rate = 0.99

exploration_rate = 1
max_exploration_rate = 1 # bounds to how small exploration rate can be
min_exploration_rate = 0.01 # bounds to how large exploration rate can be

# rate at which the exploration_rate will decay
# LR changed to 0.001 due to inconsistencies in results with larger rate - https://youtu.be/HGeI30uATws?t=57
exploration_decay_rate = 0.001
```

Reward definition:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from .... import \
    num_episodes, env, max_steps_per_episode, q_table, learning_rate, exploration_rate, discount_rate, \
    min_exploration_rate, max_exploration_rate, exploration_decay_rate

rewards_all_episodes = []

# Q-learning algorithm
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    state = env.reset()

    # Exploration/exploitation trade-off
    done = False
    rewards_current_episode = 0

    for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):


        exploration_rate_threshold = random.uniform(0,1)
        if exploration_rate_threshold > exploration_rate:
            action = np.argmax(q_table[state,:])
        else:
            action = env.action_space.sample()

        new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        #Update Q-table for Q(s,a)
        q_table[state, action] = \
            q_table[state, action] * (1 - learning_rate) + learning_rate * (reward + discount_rate *
                                                                            np.max(q_table[new_state, :]))

        state = new_state
        rewards_current_episode +- reward

        if done == True:
            break

        # Exploration rate decay - exploration rate update - https://youtu.be/HGeI30uATws?t=298
        exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate + (max_exploration_rate - min_exploration_rate) * np.exp(
            -exploration_decay_rate * episode)

        rewards_all_episodes.append(rewards_current_episode)

rewards_per_thousand_episodes = np.split(np.array(rewards_all_episodes), num_episodes/1000)
count = 1000
print("\n********Average reward per thousand episodes********")
for r in rewards_per_thousand_episodes:
    print(count, ": ", str(sum(r/1000)))
    count += 1000

print("\n********Updated Q-table********")
print(q_table)
```

Traceback info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\...\_test_Q_learning_and_Gym_run.py", line 48, in <module>
rewards_per_thousand_episodes = np.split(np.array(rewards_all_episodes), num_episodes/1000)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in split
File "C:\Users\jcst\PycharmProjects\Python_3_9_test\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\shape_base.py", line 872, in split
raise ValueError(
ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division
```

Comment: Experiment with `split` (or `array_split`) in an interactive python session.  Test small pieces of code before you use them something complex.  Good answers usually do that.

Comment: Excellent, thx. It worked with array_split. The way I normally do tutorials is to follow up with a test on own data, and then for example update/adjust on parameters, values and so to understand the mechanisms.